# Javascript: Populating a select list from a json file and displaying in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have created a space invaders game using the following tutorial: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/notearsgame/

I now need to populate a select list of states using json within the javascript. I have tried the following set up; I have created a div where the select box can be displayed.

```
<body>
    <h1>Game</h1>
      <div id="displaycontent"></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
```

I now have the callback functions to populate the list.

```
function getStates()
    {
        var url = "states_json.php";

        req = new XMLHttpRequest();

        req.open("GET", url, true);
        //req.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json; charset=utf-8");
        req.onreadystatechange = getStatesCallBack;
        req.send(null);
    }

    function getStatesCallBack()
    {
        if (req.readyState == 4)
        {
            if (req.status == 200)
            {
                var response = req.responseText.parseJSON();
                var displaycontent = document.getElementById("displaycontent");

                while (displaycontent.hasChildNodes())
                {
                    displaycontent.removeChild(displaycontent.lastChild);
                }

                var stateSelect = document.createElement("select");
                stateSelect.setAttribute("id", "stateslist");
                //artistSelect.setAttribute("onChange", "getArtistInfo()");
                displaycontent.appendChild(stateSelect);

                var state = response.statesarray;

                for (i = 0; i <state.length; i++)
                {
                    var state_id = state[i].state_id;
                    var state_name = state[i].state_name;

                    if (stateSelect != null && stateSelect.options != null)
                    {
                        stateSelect.options[stateSelect.options.length] =
                             new Option(state_name, state_id, false, true);
                    }
                }

                stateSelect.options[0].selected = true;
                displaycontent.appendChild(stateSelect);
                var stateDetailDiv = document.createElement("div");
                stateDetailDiv.setAttribute("id", "statedetails");
                displaycontent.appendChild(stateDetailDiv);
                //getArtistInfo();
            }
        }
    }
```

The game code from the tutorial follows the above code. The game works fine however there is no select list populated at all. I have checked the json file output and it is displaying the correct information so that is not the issue. I have tried debugging in firebug but it doesn't show any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML for your select list should look like this eventually:

```
<select name="stateslist">
  <option value="value1">Label For value 1</option> 
  <option value="value2">Label For value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Label For value 3</option>
</select>
```

So you should try changing the contents of your `for (i = 0; i <state.length; i++)` loop and do something like that for each iteration:

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.setAttribute('value', state_id);
option.textContent = state_name;
stateSelect.appendChild(option);
```

Comment: Corrected a mistake: use option.textContent = state_name; instead of option.nodeValue(state_name);